# U-SQL: Schematized input files

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-data-lake, u-sql

How can I use schematized input files in an U-SQL script? That is, how can I use multiple files as input to an EXTRACT clause?

According to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621320.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

and

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ad563d8-677c-46e7-bb3e-e1627025f2e9/read-data-from-multiple-files-and-folder-using-usql?forum=AzureDataLake&prof=required

I tried both

```
@rs =
    EXTRACT s_type string, s_filename string
    FROM "/Samples/logs/{s_filename:*}.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();
```

and

```
@rs =
    EXTRACT s_type string
    FROM "/Samples/logs/{*}.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();
```

Both versions resulting in an error message complaining about '*' being an invalid character.

[image: U-SQL error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File set is not supported locally so far. It will work when you run it on cloud Azure Data Lake Analytics account.